# Java windows "could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, groovy, jar

Good night.
I know this type of error is very common and i tried to search for it already, but none of the solution resolved my problem.

So i have a jar that i want to run i tried `java -jar rembrandt.jar` and got the problem `"could not find or load main class rembrandt.bin.Rembrandt"`, this jar have a series of dependencies like json and i have all the dependencies in a folder called lib, so i tried `java -cp path -jar rembrandt.jar` same error.

I extracted the jar and the class exist int the correct folder. I also have access to the code and confirmed that the class have a main function (this class is groovy but i think that shouldn't interfere).

I think may be the dependencies is there any way to confirm that and if so can i know each one?

```
 package rembrandt.bin

 import rembrandt.obj.*
 import saskia.bin.Configuration
 import rembrandt.io.*
 import org.apache.log4j.*
 import org.apache.commons.cli.*
 import java.util.jar.Manifest
 import java.util.jar.Attributes


  class Rembrandt {

    /**
     * Main method.
     */
    static void main(args) {

    def rembrandt, conf, conffilepath
    Options o = new Options()
    o.addOption("conf", true, "Configuration file")
    o.addOption("gui", true, "Activates a graphic GUI")
    o.addOption("help", false, "Gives this help information")

    CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser()
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(o, args)

    if (cmd.hasOption("help")) {
        HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        formatter.printHelp( "java rembrandt.bin.Rembrandt", o )
        System.exit(0)
    }

    if (!cmd.hasOption("conf")) {
        conffilepath = Configuration.defaultconf
        log.info "No configuration file given. Using default configuration file."
    } else {
        conffilepath = cmd.getOptionValue("conf")
        log.info "Configuration file $conffilepath given."
    }

    conf = Configuration.newInstance(conffilepath)
    rembrandt = new Rembrandt(conf)
    log.info "Rembrandt version ${Rembrandt.getVersion()}. Welcome."

    if (cmd.hasOption("gui")) {

        RembrandtGui gui = new RembrandtGui(rembrandt, conf)//)
         gui.start()
        log.info "Rembrandt GUI started."

    } else {

        log.info "Invoking reader ${rembrandt.inputreader.class.name} to parse the input stream."  

        List<Document> docs = rembrandt.loadDocuments()
        log.info "Got ${docs.size()} doc(s). "

        // give labels if the doc does not have...
        String docid_header
        if (rembrandt.inputFileName) 
            docid_header = rembrandt.inputFileName 
        else 
            docid_header = 'stdin'

        rembrandt.printHeader()

        /* stats stuff */
        def stats = new DocStats(docs.size())
        stats.begin()
        docs.eachWithIndex { doc, i->
        if (!doc.docid) doc.docid = docid_header+"-"+(i+1)
        stats.beginDoc(doc.docid)
        doc = rembrandt.releaseRembrandtOnDocument(doc)
        rembrandt.printDoc(doc)
        stats.endDoc()                                
        stats.printMemUsage()     
        }
        stats.end()
        rembrandt.printFooter()
        log.info "All Done. Have a nice day."
   }
    }
}
```

This code is part of the main class, as you can see it got a main and package is the correct one.
Thanks for your support

Comment: Is this project hosted online? Where?

Comment: here https://code.google.com/p/rembrandt/downloads/list

Comment: This is a rembrandt project. Is that your project, are you trying to run it via main class? Or do you just use rembrandt as an library? If so please provide access to the project where you use this library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the MANIFEST file.

1) Create manifest.txt

2) In manifest.txt you should add these line(s): Main-Class: Rembrandt 
and then press twice "Enter" button.

3) Create jar-file via command prompt: # jar cfm Your_Jar_file_name.jar manifest.txt

Also do not forget to add JAR files in your project (make sure, that they all in one package (folder)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer but the jar that i am running already have that information in the meta-inf folder so that should not be the problem

Comment: @user3591111 Try to delete the first line - "package rembrandt.bin". Moreover, I can not see the ";"

Comment: ; it is because it groovy and the first line is the name of the package is correct because when it calls the main it calls rembrandt.bin.Rembrandt